# Java problems associated with parameterized class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a Java Spring Boot application that makes a call of another Java application internally bypassing some information. The implementation of the called application is out of my control and I do not have access to make any changes to it.

When I make the call I get few warnings in my Intellij IDEA. I wanted to know if there are some modifications that can be done within my Spring Boot application to avoid these warnings?

Following is the call that I make in my Spring Boot application:

```
final var jsonOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
new Converter().convert(inputStream, new Handler(new Validator(), new StreamCollector(jsonOutput)));
return new String(jsonOutput.toByteArray());
```

Following are the warnings that I get in my Intellij IDEA Problems section, both these warnings are coming because of `new Handler`

> 1. Provide the parametrized type for this generic.
> 2. Raw use of parameterized class 'Handler'

As the called `new Handler` implementation is not in my control, I won't be able to make any modifications to it. Is there anything that can be done within my Spring Boot application to resolve these warnings? Also, why does it throw these warnings is it because of wrong way of coding?

Comment: Not sure but Handler may have some generic type in its implementation .. use new Handler<String> and test again

Comment: Thanks for your response. The String did not work and was throwing the error so I did the following and it seems to work fine and the warning is not displayed anymore: `new Handler<>(new EventValidator(),`

Comment: Please provide `Converter`, `Handler`, `Validator` and `StreamCollector` classes signature.

Comment: @samabcde I modified the code `new Handler<>(new EventValidator(),` and it works fine now.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 it is good that it is working .. but you may find permanent solution to it